# Object detection with Tensorflow API - No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I followed the tutorial [Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_object_detection_saved_model.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-object-detection-saved-model-py)  and received the following errors:

[Module not Found "official.legacy"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvOXB.png)

I did the following steps:

1. Open PowerShell
2. `cd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TestTensorflow`
3. `conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.11`
4. `conda activate tensorflow`
5. `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow`
6. Use verification script:
   `python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"`

Result: Successful

7. GPU support was skipped for the first step to reduce complexity
8. Download and install object detection API of TensorFlow Model Garden https://github.com/tensorflow/models (master-branch)
9. Extract .zip folder to C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TestTensorflow\Tensorflow
   Rename resulting folder “model-master” to “models”
10. `cd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TestTensorflow\Tensorflow\models\research`
11. `protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`
12. `pip install cython`
13. `pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI`
14. `cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py` .
    Result: `Successfully installed pycocotools-2.0`
15. `python -m pip install` .
16. Test installation with `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py”`
    Result = Error (see screenshot)